# Modular (pythonic) way for fitting combined parameters of a composite function

Tags: python, curve-fitting, model-fitting, lmfit

My question is about fitting parameters of a complicated model composed of different parametric functions.

More precisely, I want to describe a complicated experiment.
The experiment produces a one-dimensional array of measured data `data`, where each its entries corresponds to (a set of) experimental control variables `x`.

I now a theoretical model (actually multiple models, see below) `model(x,pars)`, which takes `x` and a lot of parameters `pars` to give a prediction for `data`. However, not all parameters are known and I need to fit them.

Moreover, some details of the model are not yet certain. Because of that, I actually have a family of multiple models which are in some parts very similar, but where some internal component of the model is different (but a large part of the model is the same).

Unfortunately, switching one component for another might introduce new (unknown) parameters, that is we now have `modelA(x,parsA)` and `modelB(x,parsB)`
 which have different parameters.

Basically, the model is composed of functions `f(x, pars, vals_of_subfuncs)` where `x` is the independent variable, `pars` are some explicit parameters of `f`, and `vals_of_subfuncs` are the results of evaluating some lower-level functions, which themselves depend on their own parameters (and maybe the results of their own lower-level functions etc.)
Obviously, there are no recursions possible, and at there is a lowest level of functions that do not rely on the value of other functions.

The situation is best illustrated in this picture:

[Modular model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ6B7.png)

The independent variable is `x` (blue), parameters are `a,b,c,d` (red), and the values of subfunctions appear as green arrows into nodes that represent functions.

In (1), we have a lowest-level function `G(x; (a,b); {})` with no sub-functions and a higher-level function `F(x; c; G(x; (a,b))` whose evaluation gives the model result, which depends on `x` and `pars=(a,b,c)`.

In (2) and (3) we change a component of the model, (`F->F'`) and (`G->G'`), respectively. This changes the parameter dependence of the final model.

Now I am looking for a most pythonic/modular way to approach the problem of implementing parameter fitting in this situation, without having to re-write the fit function everytime I swap/change a component of my model, thereby possibly introducing a new parameter.

At the moment, I am trying to find solutions to this problem using `lmfit`. I also thought about maybe trying to use `sympy` to work with symbolic "parameters", but I don't think all the functions that appear can be easily written as expressions that can be evaluated by `asteval`.

Does anyone know of a natural way to approach such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you brought up `sympy`, I think you should take a look at [`symfit`](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html), which does precisely what you ask for in the last paragraph. With `symfit` you can write symbolic expressions, which are then fitted with `scipy`. It will make it very easy for you to combine your different submodels willy-nilly.

Let me implement your second example using `symfit`:

```
from symfit import variables, parameters, Fit, Model

a, b, c = parameters('a, b, c')
x, G, F = variables('x, G, F')

model_dict = {
    G: a * x + b,
    F: b * G + c * x
}
model = Model(model_dict)
print(model.connectivity_mapping)
```

I choose these rather trivial functions, but you can obviously choose whatever you want. To see that this model matches your illustration, this is what `connectivity_mapping` prints:

```
{F: {b, G, x, c}, G: {b, a, x}}
```

So you see that this is really a mapping representing what you drew. (The arguments are in no particular order within each set, but they will be evaluated in the right order, e.g. `G` before `F`.) To then fit to your data, simply do

```
fit = Fit(model, x=xdata, F=Fdata)
fit_results = fit.execute()
```

And that's it! I hope this makes it clearer why I think `symfit` does fit your use case. I'm sorry I couldn't clarify that earlier, I was still finalizing this feature into the API so up to now it only existed in the development branch. But I made a release with this and many other features just now :).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `symfit`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am only a little familiar with `sympy`, but haven't tried `symfit`. From what I understand of the documentation, it doesn't quite fit my usecase, which is rather general. I will see how to procede. If I end up finding a solution using `symfit`, I'll post this here.

Comment: @beralt, due to a new release of `symfit` I updated my answer, because I think you might be interested in some new features.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question would definitely be improved with a more concrete example, (that is, with actual code).  If I understand correctly, you have a general model

```
def model_func(x, a, b, c, d):
     gresult = G(x, a, b, d)
     return F(x, b, c, gresult)
```

but you also want to control whether `d` and `b` are really variables, and whether `c` gets passed to `F`.  Is that correct?

If that is correct (or at least captures the spirit), then I think you can do this with `lmfit` (disclaimer: I'm a lead author) with a combination of adding keyword arguments to the model function and setting some Parameter values as fixed.

For example, you might do some rearranging like this:

```
def G(x, a, b=None, d=None):
    if b is not None and d is None:
       return calc_g_without_d(x, a, b)
    return calc_g_with_d(x, a, d) 

def F(x, gresult, b, c=None):
    if c is None:
       return calc_f_without_c(x, gresult, b)
    return calc_f_with_c(x, gresult, b, c) 

def model_func(x, a, b, c, d, g_with_d=True, f_with_c=True):
     if g_with_d:
        gresult = G(x, a, d)
     else:
        gresult = G(x, a, b)
     if f_with_c:
         return F(x, gresult, b, c=c)
     else:
         return F(x, gresult, b)
```

Now, when you make your model you can override the default values `f_with_c` and/or `g_with_d`:

```
import lmfit
mymodel = lmfit.Model(model_func, f_with_c=False)
params = mymodel.make_params(a=100, b=0.2201, c=2.110, d=0)
```

and then evaluate the model with `mymodel.eval()` or run a fit with `mymodel.fit()` and passing in explicit values for the keyword arguments `f_with_c` and/or `g_with_d`, like

```
test = mymodel.eval(params, x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 41), 
                    f_with_c=False, g_with_d=False)
```

or

```
result = mymodel.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata, g_with_d=False)
```

I think the way you have it specified, you'd want to make sure that `d` was not a variable in the fit when `g_with_d=False`, and there are cases where you would want `b` to not vary in the fit.  You can do that with

```
params['b'].vary = False
params['d'].vary = False
```

as needed.  I can imagine your actual problem is slightly more involved than that, but I hope that helps get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

I think `lmfit` might be able to do what I want, but I will have to implement the "modularity" myself.
The example I have was just conceptional and a miminal model. In general, the "networks" of function and their dependencies are much more intricate that what I do in the example.

My current plan is as follows:
I will write a class `Network` for the "network", which contains certain `Node`s.
Notes specify their possible "symbolic" dependence on sub`Node`s, explicit parameters and independent variables.

The `Network` class will have routines to check that the such constructed network is consisten. Moreover, it will have a (`lmfit`) `Parameters` object (i.e. the unification of all the parameters that the nodes explicitly depend on) and provide some method to generate an `lmfit` `Model` from that.

Then I will use `lmfit` for the fitting.

At least this is the plan.
If I succeed in building this, I will publish update this post with my code.